# Javascript string replace has no effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I have the following structure:

```
<span class="h1">Color green</span>
<div class="swatchesContainer">
    <img title="green" src="/"/>
    <img title="blue" src="/"/>
</div>
```

Now I want to change the color in the in the span to the color which is stated in the `title`of the image. (No I am not able to add a class with the color name)

I have tried te following code:

```
var product_name = jQuery(".h1").text();
jQuery(".swatchesContainer img").click(function(){

    var selected_color = jQuery(this).attr('title');
    var string;
    console.log("String before: " + product_name);

    jQuery('.swatchesContainer img').each(function(){
        string = product_name.replace(jQuery(this).attr('title').trim(),' ');
        console.log(jQuery(this).attr('title'));
    })
    console.log("String after: " + string);
    jQuery(".h1").text(string + " " +selected_color);
});
```

I'm fetching all the `title` attributes from te images and replace them from te text in the same foreach function

But the new color keeps appending after the existing color

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/03p0w446/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a flaw in your logic. Inside the loop you are repeatedly overwriting the `string` variable:

```
string = product_name.replace(...)
```

At the end of loop you will have `"Color green".replace("blue", " ")` -> `"Color green"`.

Change these lines:

```
var string;
// ...
string = product_name.replace(jQuery(this).attr('title').trim(),' ');
```

To these:

```
var string = product_name;
// ...
string = string.replace(jQuery(this).attr('title').trim(),' ');
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/03p0w446/3/)

---

Having said all that, I would rather change the markup to this:

```
<span class="h1">Color <span class="chosen-color">green</span></span>
<div class="swatchesContainer">
    <img title="green">
    <img title="blue">
</div>
```

And overwrite the contents of `.chosen-color` instead of get/match/replace the entire text inside `.h1`. Your jQuery code will be reduced to one line.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be:

```js
var span = $('.h1');
$('.swatchesContainer img').on('click', function() {
    var txtArr = span.text().split(' ');
    txtArr[1] = this.title;
    span.text( txtArr.join(' ') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="h1">Color green</span>
<div class="swatchesContainer">
    <img title="green" src="/"/>
    <img title="blue" src="/"/>
</div>
```